# Jackson @JsonPropertyOrder is ignored

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm currently developing RESTful app with Spark framework and I use Jackson for serialization. And I encountered such issue: @JsonPropertyOrder is ignored.

Here's my POJO:

```
@Data
@JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "company", "title", "infos", "startDate", "endDate"})
public class Info {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    long id;

    @JsonProperty("company")
    Company company;

    @JsonProperty("title")
    String title;

    @JsonProperty("infos")
    List<Prize> infos;

    @JsonProperty("startDate")
    Date startDate;

    @JsonProperty("endDate")
    Date endDate;

    public Info() {}
}
```

I generate JSON with this method:

```
public static String generateJSONResponse(Object response) {
    if (responseObjectMapper == null) {
        responseObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory());
        responseObjectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    }

    try {
        return responseObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(response);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // Must not occur
    }

    // Something really unexpected happened, so we return unknown response;
    return ErrorMessages.ERROR_RESPONSE_UNKNOWN;
}
```

And in the end I receive this:

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "result": {
    "infoList": [
      {
        "infos": [...],
        "id": 2,
        "title": "...",
        "company": {...},
        "startDate": 1445238000000,
        "endDate": 1445792400000
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or something is wrong with Jackson? Can anybody help me with that?

Also, I tried this using Jackson version 2.6.3 and 2.3.5. Both works the same way.

Comment: When I tried to replicate your code with Jackson 2.6.2, it seemed to work fine. Is there anything else special about your setup? What is the `@Data` annotation? Perhaps it's interfering somehow?

Comment: Excuse me, why do you want to preserve the order of the properties? [The JSON spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159) clearly says an object is an **unordered** collection "`An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value pairs, [...]`" and "`Implementations whose behavior does not depend onmember ordering will be interoperable in the sense that they will not be affected by these differences.`"

Comment: `@Data` annotation is an Lombok library annotation that saves me from writing getters and setters for each field. I don't know if it is interfering somehow, but I will look into this.

Comment: About why do I need that: simply for JSON readability by other developers.

Comment: As far as I tested, Lombok `@Data` annotation does not affect ordering anyhow. `@JsonPropertyOrder` is still ignored.

Comment: How do you solve it?

Comment: Nohow. I just closed my eyes on that.

Comment: I tried `@JsonPropertyOrder` with Jackson 2.7.3 and it's working fine. I needed to serialize the object in a specific order since a hash is calculated based on the string generated, and then recalculated again in a remote server.

Comment: Maybe this clashes somehow with autogenerated setters/getters from lombok. You may try to add `@JsonAutoDetect(
        fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY,
        isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
        getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)`

Answer (score 0):

The annotation JavaDoc also echoes the "unordered" collection: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyOrder.html

> This annotation may or may not have effect on deserialization: for
> basic JSON handling there is no effect, but for other supported data
> types (or structural conventions) there may be.

That probably explains why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

check if you are importing the correct package of "**JsonPropertyOrder**":

*this work for me:* import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

Answer (score -4):

Lomboks @Data interferes with Jackson deserializing. Remove this and try..